# 404 error when I update web application published in iis

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

I recently uploaded my web application in iis, but I have the error that when I update the web application it gives me a 404 error, I can use it without problem it is only when I update.

Comment: Could you tell me which kind of application you hosted  in IIS? Since you don’t provide much information, I suggest you try the following measures.
Check the url in browser to ensure it is right.
Check the site in IIS to ensure it is running and the physical path is right, you can restart it after uploading. Or click browse directly from the action window.
Check the permissions of the folder where the site files are located
Edit error pages setting to return detail error, maybe you can find solutions through detailed error.

Comment: Check the log file, the file will records more detailed status code and you can know specific error through it.
Check failed request tracing, the tracing will completely record the entire request to response process and information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the **IIS Admin Service**?

Please check the solution here: [link](https://support.archiver.gfi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015221579)

Comment: Please don't just add links for answers as links may go away or the content may change.